# Error message on exchange server with hybrid setup to Office365

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchange-hybrid

Hybrid setup between Exchange 2016 and Office 365, 50% of the of the users are migrated to Office 365 and currently no problems reported. A few months later (today) I discovered this error message in event viewer that shows up about once every hour, not at a specific time.

I have tried google and been asking around, but we havn‘t been able to find the problem or the cause.

1. The Id of S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx- xxxxxxxxxx -1186, is it a user or the Exchange itself?
2. Any idea of what could cause this error? I do see the word „Photo“ multiple times in the stacktrace below...

> Process 20624: ProxyWebRequest FederatedCrossForest from
>   S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx- xxxxxxxxxx -1186 to
>   https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx failed. Caller SIDs:
>   OAuth. The exception returned is
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.ProxyWebRequestProcessingException:
>   Proxy web request failed.  ---> System.Net.WebException: The request
>   failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.Proxy.Service.EndGetUserPhoto(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.UserPhotos.UserPhotoApplication.EndProxyWebRequest(ProxyWebRequest
>   proxyWebRequest, QueryList queryList, IService service, IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.ProxyWebRequest.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.InfoWorker.Common.Availability.AsyncWebRequest.EndInvokeWithErrorHandling()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- . Name of the server where exception originated: XXXXXXXXX. XXX: 43532. Make sure that the Active
>   Directory site/forest that contain the user's mailbox has at least one
>   local Exchange 2010 server running the Availability service. Turn up
>   logging for the Availability service and test basic network
>   connectivity.

Comment: Does your users can see the free/busy when they schedule meeting in example ? I think that error could be a issue with that (https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/2555008/how-to-troubleshoot-free-busy-issues-in-a-hybrid-deployment-of-on-prem)

Comment: I am afraid that free/busy in meetings works like a charm.